# How to get MYSQL database from Xamp

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

I used xampp sometime ago to run mysql server. I forgot to save a copy of my database. Now my hard drive has crashed and I can only use it as external drive. Using it as an external hard drive I can access the xampp installation folder but I can't seem to find copies of mysql databases.

So this is what i tried:

> But I found my database names in `C:\xampp\mysql\data\voting`
>   directory, where `voting` is a my database name. Now, in the `voting`
>   folder, I can find all my table names but they end in some wierd
>   extension (`.frm` or `.ibd`) that I cannot import to a new xampp that
>   I have installed. For instance there is a table in the `voting`
>   database called `candidate` .
>
> [image]

**My problems is that is there a way I can retrieve my database from the xampp installation folder?**

**If NOT, How can I get mysql database using xampp(Without sql,csv or json files)**

**NOTICE:** The xampp directory is an old one and I cannot run it because it is on a hard drive that is slightly crashed and can be access externally to a computer.

Answer (score 0):

After posting this for 3 days and getting no answer, i toiled and toiled until I got an answer.

What I did was I copied the `data` folder in `C:\xampp\mysql` directory where I installed `xampp` from my old xampp installation folder on my old hard drive.

I pasted the old `data` folder I copied into `C:\xampp\mysql` directory of my new hard drive.
**NOTICE:** there is an already existing `data` folder there, so I backed up before doing any changes.

Finally, I opened `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/` in my browser and I can now see all my old MYSQL databases.